# sublime had issue importing anaconda installed numpy

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, sublimetext3

I use sublime text to write python codes, but recently i switched to a new computer. On that computer, first I installed anaconda from https://www.anaconda.com/, then I downloaded sublime text 3, I use the tool-->build system-->new build system on the tool bar of sublime text to associate the anaconda python(/anaconda/python.exe) to sublime. Everything seemed alright, I can import regex and many anaconda packages, but when i import numpy, this error happened `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: can't find the module.`More detail in the picture posted.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9xYf.png) I tried updating numpy package with conda, didn't work. On my old computer I also have anaconda installed, but I don't remember how I set the association betweent sublime text3 and the python interpreter. On the old computer sublime, it's tool--> build system-->Python, no new built system, so maybe that is the difference... Also on the old computer I have torch installed maybe that's the difference? really need help here

Comment: Have you tried using `conda` to uninstall and then reinstall numpy?

Comment: just now I checked the version of numpy and numpy-base on my old computer, and I uninstall the numpy and numpy-base seperately by using `conda uninstall numpy --force` and `conda uninstall numpy-base --force`, then installed the old version(1.18.5) of them, and problem solved, seems like sublime text dosen't go well with the latest version of numpy, I can use the latest version of numpy on pycharm and jupyter notebook without any issue.Thanks for your advice anyway